# Opposite of C preprocessor "stringification"

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

When using C preprocessor one can stringify macro argument like this:

```
#define TO_STRING(x) "a string with " #x
```

and so when used, the result is as follows:

`TO_STRING(test)` will expand to: `"a string with test"`

Is there any way to do the opposite? Get a string literal as an input argument and produce a C identifier? For example:

`TO_IDENTIFIER("some_identifier")` would expand to: `some_identifier`

Thank you for your answers.

EDIT: For those wondering what do I need it for:

I wanted to refer to nodes in a scene graph of my 3D engine by string identifiers but at the same time avoid comparing strings in tight loops. So I figured I'll write a simple tool that will run in pre-build step of compilation and search for predefined string - for example `ID("something")`. Then for every such token it would calculate CRC32 of the string between the parenthesis and generate a header file with #defines containing those numerical identifiers. For example for the string `"something"` it would be:

`#define __CRC32ID_something 0x09DA31FB`

Then, generated header file would be included by each cpp file using `ID(x)` macros. The `ID("something")` would of course expand to `__CRC32ID_something`, so in effect what the compiler would see are simple integer identifiers instead of human friendly strings. Of course now I'll simply settle for `ID(something)` but I thought that using quotes would make more sense - a programmer who doesn't know how the `ID` macro works can think that `something` without quotes is a C identifier when in reality such identifier doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would that be useful?

Comment: You are either doing something for a really strange usecase or doing it completely wrong. Please describe the real problem.

Comment: You need a C interpreter to do that :)

Comment: For those who wanted to know, added some explanation. :)

Comment: i've googled many times to have a solution, unfortunately, there is no solution for the moment, this option (destringify) is very useful to write a factorized c codes.

Comment: This is why we should use PHP instead of C preprocessor. simply <? echo stripslashes($given); ?>. C preprocessor cannot be extended, whereas you can easily extend PHP preprocessor to include new preprocessing functions. C preprocessor cannot define functions, it can only define a php equivalent of a replace regex(preg_replace), except it can't even work with regex, it has to replace literals, and it can't even do that very well.).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, you can't unstringify something.

Comment: More generally, the preprocessor can join tokens together, but it can't break a token apart.

Answer (score 1):

```
//unstringify test

enum fruits{apple,pear};

#define IF_WS_COMPARE_SET_ENUM(x) if(ws.compare(L#x)==0)f_ret=x;

fruits enum_from_string(wstring ws)
{
 fruits f_ret;
 IF_WS_COMPARE_SET_ENUM(apple)
 IF_WS_COMPARE_SET_ENUM(pear)
 return f_ret;
}

void main()
{
 fruits f;
 f=enum_from_string(L"apple");
 f=enum_from_string(L"pear");
}
```

Comment: @FDinoff: Better not.

Comment: this may work only if you prepare your "database" made of const strings  at `enum_from_string()`, otherwise not :/, but interesting :)

Answer (score -2):

You can create an identifier from a string, this operation is called **token-pasting** in C :

```
#define paste(n) x##n
int main(){
    int paste(n) = 5;
    printf("%d" , x5);
}


output : 5
```

Comment: Token pasting does not create a token from a string (by which the OP means a string *literal*).  Token pasting creates one token out of (generally) two tokens, provided that the result is also a valid token.  A lexical merge of two tokens such as the `##` operator performs does not form a valid token  when one of the operand tokens is a string literal.