# Simple Macro Causes Compile Error

Tags: c, macros, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to define a macro that allows me to pass in 2 numbers as well as an operator. I want the macro to carry out the specified operation on the two numbers and return the result.

My definition is:

```
#define GENERAL_OP(x,y,op) ((x) op (y))
```

which works fine when I call

```
int result = GENERAL_OP(1, 2, -);
```

but as soon as I try to pass it a character (which is what I actually need to do in my
generalized function that calls the macro) as in the following example:

```
void Evaluate(char op)...

int result = GENERAL_OP(1, 2, op);
```

Comment: You could map the operators out to `std::plus` and the like.

Comment: The error is the preprocessor expansion of a runtime variable. You're code effectively becomes `(1) op (2)`. *exactly*. chris' idea of mapping char-ops to std::functions is a very elegant solution, btw, and should be considered.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm in C not C++ so that's not an option. I must have tagged it with C++ by accident.

Answer (score 9):

```
void Evaluate(char op)...

int result = GENERAL_OP(1, 2, op);
```

Macro replacement is done before compile time, but the argument of `Evaluate` is only available at runtime, so the macro expansion leads to

```
int result = ((1) op (2));
```

there, and `op` is not a token that can appear there (probably an undeclared identifier).

Comment: Ohhh okay, that makes sense actually. Is there any alternative that would achieve what I'm trying or is this just something that requires a function with different switch cases for each possible operation?

Comment: C or C++? And it depends on how many operations you want to support. For only the four arithmetic operations, I'd say a `switch` is the best option. If you have substantially more, a map `symbol -> operation` would be a good candidate, as chris suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor operates at compile-time, you can't use the value of `op` inside your macro.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're going for... it's sort of like trying to [unstringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982179/opposite-of-c-preprocessor-stringification). I'm pretty sure it can't work the way you want it to. Your best bet would be to do something like:

```
void Evaluate(char op, int x, int y)
{
    int result;
    if(op == '-')
      GENERAL_OP(x, y, -);
    ...
```

But that doesn't make it very "general"...