# How can I obtain the identifier of the current function?

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

In C/C++, we have the `__FUNCTION__` macro which is replaced with a string, holding the name of the current function. But what if I want the function's identifier? That is, not a string, but something I could use as a token to create other identifiers, e.g., if we have

```
#define MAGIC /* ... */

#define MORE_MAGIC MAGIC ## _bar

void foo() {
    printf("%s\n",__FUNCTION__);
    MORE_MAGIC();
}

void foo_bar() {
    printf("%s\n",__FUNCTION__);
}

void baz() {
    printf("%s\n",__FUNCTION__);
    MORE_MAGIC();
}

void baz_bar() {
    printf("%s\n",__FUNCTION__);
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

should print

```
foo
foo_bar
baz
baz_bar
```

---

**Notes:**

- I'm interested in preprocessing-time only.
- I would rather not replace my function definitions with a preprocessor call - although I know that would probably work.

Comment: C and C++ doesn't have [introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspection_%28computer_science%29), so it's not possible. You *could* have a hand-made mapping between function name and function pointer, but it's not possible to automate.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I believe the OP is asking about compile-time magic, rather than runtime magic (i.e. introspection).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I agree that automation in general would be difficult if not impossible, but it could be easy for special cases depending on @einpoklum's tolerance for nasty macros. You could define a DEF_FUNC macro that expands to the function prototype as well as a registration of the function in some sort of function pointer table. I.e. `DEF_FUNC(f) void f() { REGISTER(f, __FUNCTION__) `

Comment: Normally the c/c++ preprocessor doesn't do string manipulation, but if you've got more complex cases than @JoachimPileborg answer below easilty supports and are willing to venture into weird stuff there's things like this: http://insanecoding.blogspot.se/2011/10/stronger-cc-preprocesser.html

Comment: I *had* to ask: why do you think you need this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't. Because you can not *unstringify* a macro[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6982203/952747)].

In other words, you can not remove quotes around the string that generated by `__FUNCTION__` and contact it by `_bar`.

Comment: I agree. In a similar situation, where I had to write a C++ wrapper, I simply wrote a **perl script** which processed a `foo.cpp.tmpl` into the final `foo.cpp` at compile time.

Comment: Yep, `__FUNCTION__` is a string literal and there's not a thing you can do about it.

Comment: I did not say I want to un-stringify __FUNCTION__, I was wondering whether compilers, or pre-processors, offer the functionality I'm interested in, directly.

Comment: @einpoklum: I understand what you mean. One possibility in the standard C++ was un-stringifying `__FUNCTION__` which is not possible. Maybe there is a compiler magic that do it, but it's not a standard and portable way.

Answer (score 2):

If it's compile-time you want, and for a simple case like your, it might be possible with preprocessor macros and the concatenation operator `##`. Maybe something like

```
#define MORE_MAGIC(f) f##_bar

...

void foo_bar()
{
}

void foo()
{
    MORE_MAGIC(foo)();
}
```

It's not possible to get the name `foo` automatically though, it has to be explicitly named in the macro "call".