# Can I Use Macros To Convert std::tring To Corresponding Enum?

Tags: c++, enums, macros

I am trying to return an enum based on a string value (the string is from a json file, if it matters)
Basically, where in code I would write `enumName::MyName`, I want to be able to have something like

```cpp
std::string name = "MyName";
return enumName::name; // this gets converted to enumName::MyName
```

Obviously that's incorrect syntax. I had the idea of using macros to solve my problem, so here's my current attempt:

```cpp
#define stringToName(n) enumName::##n
```

Where I used the `##` token pasting operator. But in that case, `n` isn't evaluated before being copied, so the following thing happens

```cpp
return stringToName("MyName");
//which becomes
return enumName::"MyName";
```

Or

```cpp
std::string name = "MyName";
return stringToName(name);
//which becomes
return enumName::name;
```

And that's not quite what I want. Is there a way to make it work? (Ideally without having to write each and every enum name manually in a dictionary or something like that)

Comment: [The Toggle that Wouldn't](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Toggle-that-Wouldnt)

Comment: No way to do it at compile time - a string doesn't contain a value until run time.

Comment: @MarkRansom I do need it to happen at run time (when the json is being read). but now that I think about it macros would help only when compiling wouldn't they? so my idea is pretty useless.

Comment: If the language can't do what you need, reconsider what you need.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/7163069/5987 if you want to do it at runtime.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), what do you think you need this functionality for? There is probably a much simpler solution.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox well, I am working with a third-party library (SFML) and trying to import some keyboard keys from a json. SFML saves those as a very convenient enum which allows me to do some ascii manipulation to get the corresponding enum value of letters, but that won't work if I want to use other keys like numpad, control key codes, things like that.

Comment: Has someone already mentioned this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828957/enum-to-string-in-modern-c11-c14-c17-and-future-c20

Comment: Related to [opposite-of-c-preprocessor-stringification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982179/opposite-of-c-preprocessor-stringification).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found a solution using the [magic_enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum) library that was mentioned in a question linked by Jerry. I don't understand exactly how/why it works yet, but it's clean and does the job.